# Getting 404 for Tomcat Proxy Application

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

I'm trying to setup a Tomcat server.

The following is my VirtualHost config

```
<VirtualHost <hosting's ip>:80>
  ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias mail.myApp.com www.myapp.com
#  DocumentRoot /home/myappco/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@myapp.com
  UseCanonicalName Off

  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        <IfModule !mod_passenger.c>
          UserDir enabled myappco
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
 <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/myappco/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup myappco myappco
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup myappco myappco
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid myappco myappco
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    AssignUserID myappco myappco
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser myappco
    PassengerGroup myappco
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/myappco/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>
    <IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
        <FilesMatch \.(phtml|php[0-9]*)$>
            SetHandler proxy:unix:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/11fd7156a043fa23ad7e496c622a3f2dcd557177.sock|fcgi://myapp.com
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/myappco/myapp.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I was following this tutorial https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Tomcat+Proxies, since this was included in the README.APACHE-PROXY, so I basically added my proxy in the indicated *.conf file:

```
<IfModule proxy_ajp_module>
    ProxyPass "/myapp" "ajp://localhost:10001/myapp"
    ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "ajp://localhost:10001/myapp"
</IfModule>
```

The following is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" deployXML="false">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
    <Connector port="10001" protocol="AJP/1.3" xpoweredBy="false" secretRequired="false" enableLookups="true"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

It looks like the proxy is working fine, since I see a 302 redirect Status in Chrome Dev Tools, but I get a 404 when it queries for the application, even though the Tomcat startup worked fine, indicating that ajp connector is listening. Please help. I'm running out of options.

Comment: Does the application work, when Tomcat is accessed directly? To check it you'll need to add a HTTP connector to Tomcat. You can also look at Tomcat's access log to verify that requests are forwarded correctly.

Comment: Requests are getting forwarded to Tomcat and the access logs are showing the GET calls for the base application ```GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1" 404 431```. Since Tomcat is hosted via cpanel, ajp connecter is the only type of connector I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was stemming from a misconfigured POM file where the index.html file was being placed somewhere else in the war file. I simply changed the destination directory pathing to fix this issue. Apologies for the stupid error.